Trying to fetch data from spaceX API
unable to fetch data, it gave me an error that apiData is not a function. Could not understand what's the issue. Can anyone help?
const Mission = () => {
  const [apiData, setList] = useState([]);
  const [rocketData, setRocketData] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/missions/F3364BF");
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
      }
      const data = await res.json();
      setList(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (mission) => {
    setRocketData(mission);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {apiData.map((mission, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(mission)}>
          <p>{mission.mission_name}</p>
          <p>{mission.mission_id}</p>
          <p>{mission.description}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mission;

I tried some other variations but not luck.
Hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

it gave me an error that apiData is not a function - just to be sure: it did say apiData, and not apiData.map?

The problem is from the api url that you have passed into fetch. The current api returns a single mission object. You're getting the error because you're calling map on an object. If you want to fetch all the missions you should change your api url to:
fetch("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/missions")

This should fix your issue.

Yes, i realized it after some time :/ Much appreciated

Okay great. You can mark the answer as correct then.

@ketimetreveli I'm unsure why you accepted the other answer as correct when it doesn't address the specific problem of wrong api url which is the actual cause of your error that my solution addressed.

Not sure to which comment you are referring to. Plus, this is my first time here, so something might be done wrongly or missclicked
